# cannot access accordion properties in component .ts file in angular using ng-bootstrap angular 17

Tags: ng-bootstrap, angular17

I am trying to follow the documentation to access the members of an accordion from my template in my `component.ts` file. I'm having trouble finding out how they are accessing the members. I can't seem to get access to them. I've tried injection and `@ViewChild` but I can't seem to access the properties.

This is the [documentation snippet](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/overview#basic-usage) I am talking about:

> If you want to work with the accordion API, you can get either accordion or item instances from the template.
>
> ```html
> <div ngbAccordion #accordion="NgbAccordion">
>  <div ngbAccordionItem="first" #first="ngbAccordionItem" [collapsed]="false"> ... </div>
> </div>
> ```
>
> ```js
> accordion.toggle('first');  // toggle the first item
> accordion.closeAll();       // close all items
>
> first.toggle();             // toggle the first item
> first.collapsed;            // true if collapsed
> first.collapsed = true;     // collapse the first item
> first.disabled;             // true if disabled
> first.disabled = true;      // disable the first item
> first.id;                   // 'first'
> ```
>
> If an item id is not provided as in the example above, it will be generated automatically in the 'ngb-accordion-item-XXX' format.

When trying to use something like `first.toggle()` it doesn't exist for me.

Comment: `#first="ngbAccordionItem"` declares a [template reference variable](https://angular.dev/guide/templates/reference-variables) called `first`. It's accessible from ([certain](https://angular.dev/guide/templates/reference-variables#template-variable-scope)) other parts of the template (`.html`), but not accessible from the component (`.ts`).

Comment: What you probably want is a [view query](https://angular.dev/guide/components/queries#view-queries) like `@ViewChild('first') firstItem: NgbAccordionItem` (actually a specific kind called a [query locator](https://angular.dev/guide/components/queries#query-locators)) but you'll need to wait for `ngAfterViewInit()` for it to become accessible (just like any other view query).

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is a bit vague on this. Here is how I got it working.

The Html Template `component.html`:

```html
<div ngbAccordion>
  <div ngbAccordionItem>
    <div ngbAccordionHeader>
      <button ngbAccordionButton>Title</button>
    </div>
    <div ngbAccordionCollapse>
      <div ngbAccordionBody>
        <ng-template>
          <ng-content></ng-content> or just your content
        </ng-template>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The Typescript file `component.ts`:

```ts
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbAccordionDirective, NgbAccordionItem } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-accordion',
  templateUrl: './accordion.component.html'
})
export class AccordionComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(NgbAccordionDirective) private accordion: NgbAccordionDirective;
  @ViewChild(NgbAccordionItem) private accordionItem: NgbAccordionItem;

  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.accordion.collapseAll();
    this.accordionItem.toggle();
    console.log(this.accordionItem.id); //ngb-accordion-item-0
  }
}
```